# Can I track no. of purchases & profit for each session source in GA4

Tags: tracking, google-analytics-4

I want to know the profit and no. of purchases in my store that came from specific sources like Instagram & Snapchat in GA4, I did try to make a custom report from Explore in GA4 but it doesn't give me any data but no. of active visitors
Knowing that I can't use UTM because I have IGshopping such I have a URL for each product in my account on Instagram

is there any way to know how I sell and make profit and No. of events from each source In GA4?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UTM parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11242870?hl=en) and start [building](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/campaign-url-builder/) them.

You still can try going around it by looking at landing pages, referrers and trying to bind them to your transactions, but that requires a pretty good grasp on the data to properly drill in.